# How to set the style for multiple Views inside a Layout for different cases?

Tags: android, android-styles

Case 1 : Have an Image

[image]

Case 2 : Have no Image

The ImageView Would be gone, the overlay shadow will be invisible The text colors will change.

**Can this be done using styles?**

Without using styles it can be done calling a function and setting the required attributes but how to do this using style?

Here is my xml file

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/eight"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/eight">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/news_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        <!--android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/map_shadow_up"
            android:padding="@dimen/four"
            android:gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ln_hash_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/twelve"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/eight"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ln_hash"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:text="#1234"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/four"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/four"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/eight"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/eight"
                android:background="@drawable/circular_corner">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/star"
                    android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/four"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
                <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/item_ln_ratingBar"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/four"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/eight"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/eight"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/eight"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:isIndicator="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your complete XML.

Comment: copy the parent linear layout in a layout resource file and then.. when switching between the two cases.. remove all view from root relative layout and inflate the other linear layout..

Comment: @SantanuSur that can be done. I can also include layouts depending on the cases. But is there any possibility to do it using style as it is done in html css?

Answer (score 0):

I have used `attrs.xml`

there I created many references like

```
<attr name="newsImage" format="reference"/>
<attr name="overlay" format="reference"/>
<attr name="overlayHashContainer" format="reference"/>
<attr name="overlayHashContainerHash" format="reference"/>
<attr name="overlayRatingContainer" format="reference"/>
<attr name="overlayRatingContainerStar" format="reference"/>
<attr name="overlayRatingContainerRating" format="reference"/>
```

in `styles.xml`

I defined a classes like

```
<style name="NewsContainer.ItemWithImage">
    <item name="newsImage">@style/NewsContainerItemWithImageNewsImage</item>
    <item name="overlay">@style/NewsContainerItemWithImageOverlay</item>
    <item name="overlayHashContainer">@style/NewsContainerItemWithImageOverlayHashContainer</item>
    <item name="overlayHashContainerHash">@style/NewsContainerItemWithImageOverlayHashContainerHash</item>
    <item name="overlayRatingContainer">@style/NewsContainerItemWithImageOverlayRatingContainer</item>
    <item name="overlayRatingContainerStar">@style/NewsContainerItemWithImageOverlayRatingContainerStar</item>
    <item name="overlayRatingContainerRating">@style/NewsContainerItemWithImageOverlayRatingContainerRating</item>
</style>

<style name="NewsContainer.ItemWithOutImage">
    <item name="newsImage">@style/NewsContainerItemWithOutImageNewsImage</item>
    <item name="overlay">@style/NewsContainerItemWithOutImageOverlay</item>
    <item name="overlayHashContainer">@style/NewsContainerItemWithOutImageOverlayHashContainer</item>
    <item name="overlayHashContainerHash">@style/NewsContainerItemWithOutImageOverlayHashContainerHash</item>
    <item name="overlayRatingContainer">@style/NewsContainerItemWithOutImageOverlayRatingContainer</item>
    <item name="overlayRatingContainerStar">@style/NewsContainerItemWithOutImageOverlayRatingContainerStar</item>
    <item name="overlayRatingContainerRating">@style/NewsContainerItemWithOutImageOverlayRatingContainerRating</item>
</style>
```

It worked for me by calling

```
context.setTheme(R.style.NewsContainer_ItemWithImage);
context.setTheme(R.style.NewsContainer_ItemWithOutImage);
```

In the xml file i added the references of `attrs.xml`

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/news_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        style="?newsImage" />
```